# Textfield value getting cleared on closing keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, appwrite

I am working on an Appwrite project for a Netflix clone. In the Signin screen, after I enter the email and password in their respective TextFields, upon closing the keyboard, the content of the email TextField gets cleared.

**Gif below for reference**.

[image]

**The relevant code**:

```
class _OnboardingScreenState extends State<OnboardingScreen> {
  final TextEditingController _nameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();

  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  Widget _renderSignIn() {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(60, 0, 60, 0),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Center(
            child: Image.asset(Assets.netflixLogo1, width: 200),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 60),
          TextField(
            controller: _emailController,
            autofocus: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.grey,
              labelText: 'Email',
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: 0.1,
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          TextField(
            controller: _passwordController,
            obscureText: true,
            autofocus: false,
            autocorrect: false,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              filled: true,
              fillColor: Colors.grey,
              labelText: 'Password',
              floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
              border: InputBorder.none,
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20.0),
          SizedBox(
            width: double.infinity,
            child: OutlinedButton(
              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                side: const BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
              ),
              child: const Text(
                "Sign in",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 22.0),
              ),
              onPressed: () async {
                final api = context.read<AccountProvider>();
                final email = _emailController.text;
                final password = _passwordController.text;

                if (email.isEmpty || password.isEmpty) {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (_) => AlertDialog(
                            title: const Text('Error'),
                            content: const Text(
                                'Please enter your email and password'),
                            actions: [
                              TextButton(
                                child: const Text('OK'),
                                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                              )
                            ],
                          ));

                  return;
                }

                await api.login(email, password);
              },
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 40.0),
          MaterialButton(
            child: const Text(
              "Don't have an account? Sign up",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = 1;
              });
            },
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 10.0),
          MaterialButton(
            child: const Text(
              "Forgot your password?",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    final current = context.watch<AccountProvider>().current;

    _emailController.text = current?.email ?? "";

    return Scaffold(
        extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
        body: IndexedStack(
          index: _selectedIndex,
          children: [
            _renderSignIn(),
            _renderSignUp(),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

What is wrong in the code which causes the said behaviour and how to fix it?

Comment: Problem is with line `_emailController.text = current?.email ?? "";` in your `build` method. Put there log to see when it's called.

Comment: Take a look for reason why is `build` method called in documentation https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html. I would bet on `After a dependency of this State object changes (e.g., an InheritedWidget referenced by the previous build changes).`.

Answer (score 1):

Problem with build method. On dismiss keyboard `build()` method call and your current variable get empty value.

You can move this `current` variable in `initState` method.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final current = Provider.of(AccountProvider,listen:false).current;
    _emailController.text = current?.email ?? "";
  }
```